# Extracting data elements from large unstructured text files with Python

Tags: python, parsing, text, export-to-csv

I am trying to extract data elements from large unstructured text files (1,000,000 to 15,000,000 lines per file) with no consistent delimiter.  The order of the data elements are consistent.

```
Sample data:

  NAME    FIRSTNAME LASTNAME    DATE-OF-BIRTH        01/01/2019   ID-NUMBER  123     
  ADDRESS-1  1234 FAKE STREET                        COUNTY-CODE    123                             
  ADDRESS-2                                                                            
  CITY       NOWHERE                STATE   OH   ZIP  12345                            
RANDOM DATA .... 700+ LINES
  NAME  FIRSTNAME2 LASTNAME2    DATE-OF-BIRTH        01/01/2019   ID-NUMBER 4567    
  ADDRESS-1           123456 OTHER STREET            COUNTY-CODE  45678                                  
  ADDRESS-2                                                                            
  CITY      SOMEWHERE               STATE   MI   ZIP  65432                            
RANDOM DATA .... 700+ LINES
```

I'm looking for a way to create a CSV output with the values of a few fields listed below:

```
NAME, COUNTY-CODE, ZIP
FIRSTNAME LASTNAME, 123, 12345
FIRSTNAME2 LASTNAME2, 45678, 65432
```

The data is NOT tab delimited and spacing will vary.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When you say "RANDOM DATA.... 700+" lines, is that data also NAME FIRSTNAME LASTNAME.... or is that something entirely different?

Comment: No each data element is unique. When I put that ‘random data’ it’s over 700 lines of other customer information and transactional data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm...

I assume that you have a bunch of lines, each containing pairs `ID VALUE`, and that each *chunk* starts with the id `NAME`.

So I would use the `re` module to search for the expected patterns, the occurence of NAME starting a new element. As real first and last names can use more than one single word (John Fitzgerald Kennedy), I would take the NAME to be everything between NAME and DATE-OF-BIRTH.

IMHO a simple way is to build a dict when parsing the lines, and write the dict using a DictWriter whenever NAME is reached, and at end of file. I would only keep the first occurence of each keyword if more that one was found, but you could also raise an exception.

Code could be

```
import re
import csv

# prepare the patterns to search for
name = re.compile(r"NAME\s+(.*)\s+DATE")
zip_code = re.compile(r"ZIP\s*([0-9]+)")
county_code = re.compile(r"COUNTY-CODE\s*([0-9]+)")

with open("input.txt") as fdin, open("output.csv", newline='') as fdout:
    wr = csv.DictWriter(fdout, fieldnames=['NAME', 'COUNTY-CODE', 'ZIP'])
    elt = {}
    wr.writeheader()
    for line in fdin:
        # process NAME
        mx = name.search(line)
        if mx:
            if elt:                    # write previous dict if any
                wr.writerow(elt)
            elt = {'NAME': mx.group(1).strip()}   # initialize a new dict
        # process other keywords
        if not 'COUNTY-CODE' in elt:              # only keep first one
            mx =  county_code.search(line)
            if mx:
                elt['COUNTY-CODE'] = mx.group(1).strip()   # update the dict with it
        if not 'ZIP' in elt:
            mx = zip_code.search(line)
            if mx:
                elt['ZIP'] = mx.group(1)
    wr.writerow(elt)                                # don't forget last dict
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is very similar to the one found [in other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53379893/parsing-dhcpd-conf-with-textx/).

The solution is to construct partial grammar which parses the structure of the recognized construct while skipping what can't be recognized.

In your case, using [textX](https://github.com/textX/textX), that would be something along these lines (I haven't tested it but you get the picture):

```py
from textx import metamodel_from_str

mm = metamodel_from_str(r'''
    File: ( /(?s:.*?(?=NAME))/ persons*=Person | 'NAME' )*
          /(?s).*/;

    Person:
        'NAME' first_name=Name last_name=Name birth_date=Date
        'ADDRESS-1' address_1=UntilEOL
        'ADDRESS-2' address_2=UntilEOL
        'CITY' city=UntilEOL
    ;

    Name: /\w+/;
    Date: /\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/;
    UntilEOL[noskipws]: /.*?\n/;
''')

data_model = mm.model_from_file('some_input_file.txt')

# Here data_model is an object with attribute `persons`
# where each person have attributes `first_name`, `last_name`, ...
# from the `Person` rule above.
```

Note: This solution assume that the start of structural part must have a keyword `NAME`, but it is ok for the keyword to be found in the random data as on invalid parse of the rule `Person` the parser will consume the word `NAME` and continue.

Depending on your actual data you will have to tune the grammar a bit (e.g. particular regexes).